# MongoDb Aggregation, group with data on fields

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo

the following data in my mongo-db is
Input:

```
[
  {
    "year": "2022-10-01",
    "Area": "abc",
    "Engineering": 100,
    "Commerce": 20,
    "Arts": 10
  },
  {
    "year": "2022-10-01",
    "Area": "def",
    "Engineering": 90,
    "Commerce": 60,
    "Arts": 40
  },
  {
    "year": "2021-01-01",
    "Area": "abc",
    "Engineering": 70,
    "Commerce": 30,
    "Arts": 90
  },
  {
    "year": "2022-01-01",
    "Area": "def",
    "Engineering": 100,
    "Commerce": 10,
    "Arts": 50
  }
]
```

there are records of several years based on each area
final result to be in this form where first is grouped by date and then grouped by area
within each area sum of each department

Outcome:

```
{
  "2022-10-01": {
    "abc": {
      "Engineering": "<total engineering count>",
      "Commerce": "<total commerce count>",
      "Arts": "<total arts count>"
    },
    "def": {
      "Engineering": "<total engineering count>",
      "Commerce": "<total commerce count>",
      "Arts": "<total arts count>"
    }
  },
  "2021-01-01": {
    "abc": {
      "Engineering": "<total engineering count>",
      "Commerce": "<total commerce count>",
      "Arts": "<total arts count>"
    },
    "def": {
      "Engineering": "<total engineering count>",
      "Commerce": "<total commerce count>",
      "Arts": "<total arts count>"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Query

- group by `year,area` and sum the count
- group by year only and collect to an array the docs
- query is finished, but remains the transformations to put data in fields place 2x (year+area), and combine all to 1 document
- `$arrayToObject` 2x for the area nested and for the year outer
- replace-root with that document
- group to put all in 1 document
- replace root with that document

*data on fields make things hard in mongodb without them the query would be only the first 2 simple groups

[Playmongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=629df51391b564fc1e7e9598)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$group": 
   {"_id": {"year": "$year", "Area": "$Area"},
    "Engineering": {"$sum": "$Engineering"},
    "Commerce": {"$sum": "$Commerce"},
    "Arts": {"$sum": "$Arts"}}},
 {"$group": 
   {"_id": "$_id.year",
    "docs": 
     {"$push": 
       {"k": "$_id.Area",
        "v": 
         {"Engineering": "$Engineering",
          "Commerce": "$Commerce",
          "Arts": "$Arts"}}}}},
 {"$replaceRoot": 
   {"newRoot": 
     {"$arrayToObject": 
       [[{"k": "$_id", "v": {"$arrayToObject": ["$docs"]}}]]}}},
 {"$group": {"_id": null, "docs": {"$mergeObjects": "$$ROOT"}}},
 {"$replaceRoot": {"newRoot": "$docs"}}])
```